# How to use npm with docker in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, npm

I am using a docker setup like [here](https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel) for Laravel.

In my `docker-compose.yml` I have my own npm service:

```
npm:
    image: node:14.6
    container_name: npm-memberportali
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - lahmi
```

Calling `docker-compose run --rm npm install` works fine. However, calling
`docker-compose run --rm npm run dev` fails with:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'

Require stack:
- /var/www/node_modules/.bin/npm
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1065:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:911:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at /var/www/node_modules/.bin/npm:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_modules/.bin/npm:153:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1236:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/www/node_modules/.bin/npm' ]
}
```

I am using this docker setup for multiple Laravel projects and so far it always worked. Any clues why it fails here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change node version to the latest `14.x` in docker-compose and try to reinstall.

Comment: Latest version that I found was `node:14.15`. Tried that but same error.

Comment: Have you removed `node_modules` dir before installing again? Usually it helps with this error.

Comment: Omygosch it works. Thank you so much. I was suffering the whole day because of that.